# connection timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, connection

I'm using visual studio 2015 with sql server 2012,
I tried connecting to the server with windows authentication but there is error msg like this :

> connection timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. this could be because the pre login handshake failed or the server unable to respond back in time. 
>   the duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was inistilization=13482 handshake=14519.

I already tried to :

- check the login detailes and server name
- login to SQL Server Management Studio with same details
- turn off proxy.
- turn off firewall.
- check if all TCP\IP configuration in configuration manager enabled.
- check all set to port 1433

Is there is any other solution I didn't check? Please let me know...

Comment: We are getting the same error and just installed updates today. Did you install Windows updates?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012, face the same problem too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured it out, 
apparently, there are too many subnets on our system
we connect directly my IP with the server IP with a specific port (1433) using the rule on the firewall. Now all works.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should try IP address instead of using server name in the connectionstring or the line by which you are connecting to the database.

Comment: This did it for me, with some additional steps